# How to access a variable in argparse with a space in the add_argument function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

```
import argparse


parser= argparse.ArgumentParser(description='argparse module example')

parser.add_argument('domain name', action='store', nargs=1, help='specify a domain name')

args1 = parser.parse_args()
print(args1['domain name'])
```

The above code fails. Why?
How do I access the domain name input from the command line?

I realize that I could make the argument variable just "domain" and could then access args1.domain but then the output at the command line when incorrect parameters are specified appear as "domain" whereas I want to see "domain name."

ANSWER, which is posted below: use the metavar parameter in the add_argument function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that `dest` you have a couple of options:

```
args1 = parser.parse_args(['foobar'])

In [506]: args1
Out[506]: Namespace(**{'domain name': ['foobar']})
```

convert to dictionary:

```
In [507]: vars(args1)
Out[507]: {'domain name': ['foobar']}
In [508]: vars(args1)['domain name']
Out[508]: ['foobar']
```

Use the general purpose `getattr`:

```
In [509]: getattr(args1,'domain name')
Out[509]: ['foobar']
```

`argparse` uses `getattr` and `setattr` to access the Namespace.  That way it imposes minimal constraints on the naming of arguments.  But to access as

```
args.foobar
```

the dest has to be a valid variable name.

And yes, as you answer, with the `metavar`, there's no real reason for using a more complicated `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer is to use the parameter metavar='... name ...' in the add_argument() function so that it's displayed differently in -h text.